# Practical interpretation for $u_t = \log(x_t) - \log(x_{t-1})$

Tags: time-series

I have a time series $x_t$. If I use the transformation $u_t = log(x_t) - log(x_{t-1})$, my new time series $u_t$ has properties of white noise (random). I wonder whether there is any practical interpretation for $u_t$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can treat it as an approximate growth rate.

Comment: See also discussion [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244199/why-is-it-that-natural-log-changes-are-percentage-changes-what-is-about-logs-th)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a continuous-time process $x_t$ is [geometric brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) it would have this property, or the discrete-time equivalent (geometric random walk).

A difference in logs is is (for $u_t$ small at least) effectively a percentage change.

See also the connection to the *[force of mortality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_of_mortality)* (what actuaries used to call the hazard function, or rather they seem to be using it less these days) and the [force of interest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Force_of_interest), which are 'instantaneous' equivalents of your annualized (or more generally, *periodized*) discrete measure.

Comment: Why only for $u_t$ small?

Comment: Hi @PeterFlom, for $u_t$ small because of the approximation of $ln(1 + u) = u$. This is what I think.

Comment: @peterFlom The *actual* percentage change would be $(x_t-x_{t-1})/x_{t-1}$ (well, times 100% I guess); this is not the same as $log(x_t/x_{t-1})$ when the percentage change is large.

Answer (score 3):

If $u_{t}$ is near 0, then after multiplication by 100 it could be interpreted as percentage change of $x$ minus 100% from period $t-1$ to $t$ , that is beacause we could approximate $log(x_{t}/x_{t-1})$ by $x_{t}/x_{t-1}-1$ "very near" the point $x=1$, when $x$ is far away from 1 this approximation doesn't hold. Put functions $y=log(x)$ and $y=x-1$ on one plot.

Comment: Thanks @Qbik, this is what I also guess. Thanks for your help.