# Should i make correlation matrix of (1) first difference logarithm, (2) logarithm or (3) the natural numbers?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, descriptive-statistics, logarithm, differences

I am currently working on a project where I am looking at how prices are affected by changes in the exchange rates. For an example, I want to see how a change in my currency (Norwegian Kroner) affects our salesprice in foreign currency in places like France and Italy (in euros).

I want to find the effects the exchange rate have on the salesprice. Should I make a correlation matrix with (1) logarithm of first difference, (2) logarithm or (3) the normal salesprice in euro?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the natural logarithm of each price, then subtract them to get the ratio of the change. Then compare the Kroner ratios to the euro ratios. Unlike x1/x2, ln(x1)-ln(x2) is symmetric for price increases and decreases.

See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244199/why-is-it-that-natural-log-changes-are-percentage-changes-what-is-about-logs-th)