# Log-Level Model Parameter

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

Consider we have a population regression function (log-level model) with only one independent variable:
$$\log(y) = B_0 + B_1 \times x_1+u$$

In order to find the relationship between the increase of $x_1$ and $y$, I initially give $x_1$ value of 1, then:
$$\log(y_1) = B_0 + B_1 \times{1} + u $$

And also, to find the change in $y$ as an increase in $x_1$, I also give $x_1$ value of 2:

$$\log(y_2) = B_0 + B_1 \times 2 + u$$

So to compare the changes in y:
$$\log(y_2)-\log(y_1) = B_1$$

$$\log(y_2/y_1) = B_1$$
$$e^{B_1} = \frac{y_2}{y_1}$$

So, to find the percentage change in $y$:
$$\frac{y_2-y_1}{y_1}=\frac{y_2}{y_1}-1$$
$$\frac{y_2-y_1}{y_1} = e^{B_1}-1 $$

However, if $B_1$ is not lower than $0.05$, then we cannot say a one unit increase in $x$ will lead to increase in $y$ by $(e^{B_1}-1)100\%$. How should approach this problem?

Comment: Sorry, why does $B_1$ need to be lower than 0.05?

Comment: Consider $B_1=2$, then $e^2-1 = 6.38 $. So, it is not approximately equal to $(2)100\%=\%200$. But for $B_1 = 0.05$, $e^{0.05}-1 = 0.051$ can be taken as $(0.05)100\%=\%5$

Comment: But that sets the limit as $\log(2) \approx 0.7$ not $0.05$

Comment: In any case I think you should look at the answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244199/why-is-it-that-natural-log-changes-are-percentage-changes-what-is-about-logs-th. In general we interpret coefficient $B_1$ itself as the percentage when the ratio of outcomes $\frac{y_2}{y_1} \approx 1 $